# Difference between 'export' and 'export default' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What exactly is the difference between the two? I've seen people use:

```
function foo () {
  ...
}

export default foo;
```

And I've seen:

```
function bar () {
  ...
}

export bar;
```

Also, why would you use the one over the other?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If your need is to export multiple objects go with named exports(without default keyword).

```
function x1(){};
function x2(){};
export {x1},{x2};  //my-module.js
import {x1},{x2} from 'my-module';
```

otherwise for a single export, default export works well

```
export default function x1() {};
import x1 from 'my-module';
```

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with the `default` keyword

Comment: Agreed with @ieXcept. the `default` keyword has nothing to do with multiple exports. It is named vs unnamed exports.

Comment: Default is technically still a named export. It’s exported under `default` name.

Answer (score 159):

It's easiest to just look at what the three different ES6 import/export styles compile down to in CommonJS.

```
// Three different export styles
export foo;
export default foo;
export = foo;

// The three matching import styles
import {foo} from 'blah';
import foo from 'blah';
import * as foo from 'blah';
```

Roughly compiles to:

```
exports.foo = foo;
exports['default'] = foo;
module.exports = foo;

var foo = require('blah').foo;
var foo = require('blah')['default'];
var foo = require('blah');
```

(Actual compiler output may differ)