# Webpack & Typescript image import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm working on a **React** application and using **Webpack** & **Typescript**. I would like to use an image in one of the `<img/>` tags. However, I did not find the proper way to have access to the image files.

**webpack.config.js**:

```
 ...
 module: {
        rules: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'assets/[name].[ext]',
                }
            }
        ]
```

**app.tsx**:

```
...
render() {
    return <img src='/assets/logo-large.png' alt="logo"/>
}
```

When running the app, the `assets/logo-large.png` resource is not found.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Setup Webpack file-loader, add declaration.d.ts, and voila!

after spending some time to figure out the solution, this is what I did...

#### Step 1

ensure that you have installed `file-loader` as a dev dependency by

`npm install -D file-loader`, if you use yarn `yarn add -D file-loader`

#### Step 2

add the loader corresponding to the file extension in the Webpack rules `webpack.config.js`, like this

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      ...,
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jp2|webp)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

#### Step 3

create an `index.d.ts` file next to your `tsconfig.json` file, actually you can name it whatever you want but you have to follow step 4.

Since Webpack now is going to handle several image extensions so you can add other image formats supported by [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader)

```js
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.jpg';
```

#### Step 4

go to your `tsconfig.json` file and add `index.d.ts` to the include array like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src", "index.d.ts"] /// <-- Like this!!
}
```

be aware that if you haven't defined an `include` array, typescript by default is going to add all the files on the root folder, if you just define one file and not the file that contains all your code it is not going to compile. I think is a good practice to have all your code within the src folder.

Voila!!

Comment: Yikes - this gave me errors in so many of my node_modules

Comment: fyi this is how it's done with create react app: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts

Answer (score 71):

Alternatively, in your custom_typings folder (if you have that), you can add a new `import-png.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

So you can import an image using:

```
import myImg from 'img/myImg.png';
```

Alternatively, as reported by @mario-petrovic, you sometimes need to use a different export option as below (export = syntax). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42479216/319711) for the differences between the two approaches:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export = value;
}
```

In which case you probably need to import the image as:

```
import * as myImg from 'img/myImg.png';
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use wildcards in module declarations. That's super neat!

Comment: Just to add to this answer. I tried it with this solution and it didnt work. I made question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100401/typescript-image-import/51156173#51156173 . The problem was compile time error. When you correct `export default value` to `export = value` you will get typechecking correct and it will work. Thanks for leading to the final solution.

Comment: To use the image, I had to do `<img src={myImg} />`. Is that correct?

Comment: Great catch :). But I have a question, why typescript has to to this image loading thing different than js version of reactJS. @ErikVullings

Comment: @husnu Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but TypeScript needs type information when you try to import something, and as an image does not have this (i.e. has no image.d.ts file), you need to supply that information yourself.

Comment: @ErikVullings even if typescript requires a type info for images. We are just passing the type `any`, so when we thing deeply, is not this redundant

Comment: @husnu TypeScript requires you to type things, even if you type it with any. Is this redundant, perhaps yes, but at least made you explicitly think about it.

Comment: If you, like me, came across this issue and thought that the part about making a new file for the declaration was an unimportant detail, read [this old issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28097) and see why you need a separate file to make the `declare` stick.

Comment: Typescript: something that should be really simple, is now really complex. Not good.

Answer (score 24):

You need to `require` the image and then use that variable as the source, like so:

```
// At the top of the file, with all other imports/requires
const imageSrc = require('/assets/logo-large.png')

...

render() {
    return <img src={String(imageSrc)} alt="logo"/>
}
```

Comment: Only this one worked for me with typescript.

Answer (score 5):

For *Webpack 5*, there are built-in `Assets Modules` that replace the old loaders.

If you're upgrading, make sure you aren't loading assets twice. If you are you can set the Assets Module type to `javascript/auto`, like so:

```js
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
  use: [
     {
       loader: 'url-loader',
       options: {
         limit: 8192,
       }
     },
   ],
   type: 'javascript/auto'
}
```

If you are starting with a fresh webpack config, there's no longer a need to install any of the loaders, nor use them in the config. Simply follow the steps mentioned by @Carlos, skipping step #1 and replacing the code in step #2 with the following:

```js
rules: [ 
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jp2|webp)$/,
    type: 'asset/resource'
  },
//further sexiness
]
```

Comment: I'm still getting the "Cannot find module './image.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)" error with this.

Comment: @SamSverko I'd think maybe it's failing to register the module declaration for png files for some reason? From my working project, I am able to use the above webpack config, given that an "index.d.ts" exists in my root project directory with the with the following module declaration:   ```declare module "*.png"; ```

Comment: @SamSverko Just for good measure, he's how you would import afterward: `import CoolPicNoBrackets from './images/image.png'; ` and then consume like so: `<img src={CoolPicNoBrackets} alt='Less cool but still important' />`

Comment: I needed to add a `declarations.d.ts` inside my `src/` folder. Adding to the project root didn't work for some reason...

Comment: This didn't work for me - we are indeed using webpack 5

Answer (score 1):

The `copy-webpack-plugin` might solve your problem as well, when you have a lot of images you can just serve them all from one central `dist` folder.

`npm install --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin`

```
    plugins: [
        ...
        ...
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from:'src/images',to:'images'} 
        ]), 
    ...
    ]
```

No you can simply at the relative path to your image tag:

`<img src='images/your-image.png' />`

Source: https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/copy-all-images-files-to-a-folder-using-copy-webpack-plugin-7c8cf2de7676

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you do not require webpack for using **webp** images. This solution works for **TypeScript** and **JavaScript** based react apps as well. TypeScript gives an error if you try to import **webp** image as **ReactComponent**. So you should not import it as a component, but use only the source of image. Check this example:

```
import img from "./images/image.webp";
```

Now you can use this src in your  tag like this.

```
<img src={img} />
```