# "Module not found", image imports in React

Tags: reactjs, import

So, I faced the problem.
I have a folder with images

[image: imagefolder]

And import images like this:

[image: importimages]

Use images:

[image]

And still, have this problem:

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in sandbox? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: Try `<img src={require(logo1x)} />`

Comment: Where is the error? You just copied the code

Comment: try without the "."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing images in TypeScript React - "Cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module)

Comment: @DennisVash i try this. After all the actions the problem started to be highlighted inside the code like: "Cannot find module './images/logo1x.png' or its corresponding type declarations."