# Gatsby with Typescript importing assets error (ts2307)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import, gatsby, tsconfig

I am trying to add images using **import**

```
import image from '../assets/images/picture.jpg
```

am using Typescript with gatsby ... the strange thing is **it works fine with normal javascript** (**.js  ~ .jsx file**) but when I use (**.ts ~ .tsx file**) it throw out this error

> Cannot find module '../assets/images/picture.jpg' or its corresponding type declarations.**ts(2307)**

The strange thing is it works fine with normal components like

```
import Header from '../components/Header'
```

here is my **tsconfig.json** file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

and here is **gatsby-config.json file**

```
module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
      options: {
        isTSX: true, // defaults to false
        jsxPragma: `jsx`, // defaults to "React"
        allExtensions: true, // defaults to false
      },
      
    },
  ],
}
```

**folder Structure**

- src

  - components

    - MainComponent.tsx
    - Header.tsx
  - assets

    - images

      - picture.jpg

Comment: Can you share your project structure?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I added it

Comment: Typescript doesn't handle image imports, webpack does. Perhaps just change allExtensions back to false.

Comment: actually, it does...I used image imports in react using typescript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create index.d.ts file in folder src, and add this line

```
declare module "*.jpg"
declare module "*.png"
declare module "*.svg"
```

Ref: [Importing images in TypeScript React - "Cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module)

Thanks [ferran-buireu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5585371/ferran-buireu) for clearing out all queries.

Answer (score 1):

This is redundant:

```
import Header from '../components/Header'
```

Because they are in the same folder, you just can:

```
import Header from './Header'
```

Regarding the asset, you can follow this similar issue [Importing images in TypeScript React - "Cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module) to get some ideas but you can easily fix it by:

```
const image = require('../assets/images/picture.jpg')
```

*Note: I guess it's a typo from the answer but you are missing a trailing quote in the importation at `import image from '../assets/images/picture.jpg` <-- here*

In addition, try changing back to false the `allExtensions` boolean:

```
    allExtensions: false,
```

*Credits to [Kyle Mathews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182702/kyle-mathews)*

Comment: In the beginning thanks Ferran For your help.
but the point is the example I build her is just similar to the one I had the issue with..but the point is I use this code ( import image from '../assets/images/picture.jpg') normally in react applications with typescript and everything works fine..it just doesn't work with gatsby

Comment: It's because of the declaration and the `include` rule of your `tsconfig.json`. Check Gatsby's example https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-typescript/tsconfig.json

Comment: I use the same thing in react and it works..why id doesn't work with gatsby

Comment: Typescript plugin has some caveats (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-typescript/#caveats) that's why the same configuration may not exactly work