# The image import in Typescript is throwing " /src/public/images/Image.png:1 �PNG ^ ParseError: Unexpected character '�' "

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, tsconfig, parse-error

`declare module '*.png';`  **index.d.ts**

`include :[ "./src/index.d.ts",]` **tsconfig.json**

By importing image as `import Image from "./public/assets/Images/Image.png` I faced module can't find, then I added the created a file and added it in tsconfig.json. Yet facing the above mentioned error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing images in TypeScript React - "Cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module)

Answer (score 0):

I had another module declaration in index.d.ts file which was using import.

try to move import inside the declaration:

From:

```
import "@emotion/react";

declare module "@emotion/react" {
    export interface Theme {
        color: string;
    }
}

declare module '*.jpg';
```

To:

```
declare module "@emotion/react" {
    import "@emotion/react";

    export interface Theme {
        color: string;
    }
}

declare module '*.jpg';
```

*** NOTE ***

This has solved current issue but created another one with imports from @emotion/react.
Finally I moved @emotion/react declaration to separate file, e.g: emotion.d.ts