# Displaying Static Image Without Having to Modify Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I've been building out a web application using Typescript & React and during local development I wanted to display a local jpeg as a default user profile image. I received this import error when trying to use the image directly: `Cannot find module '../assets/default_profile.png' or its corresponding type declarations.`

The component file:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import img from '../assets/default_profile.png'

const ProfileImage = styled.div`
  background-image: url(img);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
`;

const ProfilePhoto = () => {
  return <ProfileImage />;
};

export default ProfilePhoto;
```

This whole thing led me down a rabbit hole of SO. This one recommended adding the `.d.ts` declaration file and then altering the `tsconfig.json` file: [Importing images in TypeScript React - "Cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module)

That didn't work for me.

This [article](https://dev.to/minompi/add-images-to-a-react-project-with-typescript-4gbm) recommended npm installing `file-loader` and then altering the webpack config.

I didn't want to go messing with the webpack config since that seems like it will be it's own can of worms and in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48395890/12487960) it was mentioned it is generally better to not eject the webpack config that is generated with create-react-app.

So I guess what I am trying to do here is tie all these similar posts together and get some consensus.

What is my best course of action? Do I need to `npm run eject` and modify my webpack config? Is there an easier way? Should I even be trying to display an image that is locally on my machine (e.g. is there 3rd party hosting that would just be easier to point to a url?)?

Appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://github.com/gokul1630/template-react) repo, I made the repo for your issue