# Problems importing images with react .tsx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, tsx

So I’m trying to import 2 images in this code. They are located in the same folder as the .tsx file

```
import * as React from 'react'
import './index.css';
import image from './image.jpg';
 import image2 from './image2.jpg';

export default function Sl2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1
        Introduzione
      </h1>
      <p>
       Lorem ipsum
      </p>
     <img src={image} style={{ width: '200%', height: '200%', transform: 'translate(110%, 0%)' }} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now if I edit src={image} with src={image2} it doesn’t work, even if both of the images are in the same folder. The error giving is “module not found”. It seems to only work with image and not image2. I also tried editing the “image.jpg” name to something else, and then I also changed it in the code, but everything seems to work ONLY if the image imported has the name “image”

Comment: this should help you [blog](https://dev.to/minompi/add-images-to-a-react-project-with-typescript-4gbm). 
It explains in details, how to import files like jpg in code with typescript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing images in TypeScript React - "Cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759220/importing-images-in-typescript-react-cannot-find-module)