# import image when running compiler with `allowJS:true`

Tags: typescript, tsc

I want to create a React Native library using JavaScript instead of typescript, but I want to take an advantage of TSC because I use jsdoc comment, and TSC can generate a type declaration from jsdoc. But I have a problem that my local image is not included when ts compiler running.

I've tried [Solution#4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73009114/8943429) but still my images not included in `dist/Images` when `tsc` run.

```
+ src
  + //another folder
  + Images
    - Images.js // here i add require('./error.png') 
    - error.png
  - index.js
  - declaration.d.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
```

`tsconfig.json` :

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "src/declaration.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // other options
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJS": true
  }
}
```

Is there any way to included `src/Images/error.png` into `dist` folder while running `tsc`?

Comment: Please do not use code formatting for non-code content.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this properly with tsc. Ideally you would get your images from a completely different folder, unrelated to your code

Comment: @MrDiamond should i create asset folder for list of images? i don't create asset folder because i only used 1 image in my library for now

Answer (score 0):

For the React-based project, the better and most recommended approach is to include these images in an assets folder. for an images folder, where separately you can manage images or any other CSS, JS(3rd party files) there. This is the way most developers use for enterprise-level applications and even for small applications.