# Import images like in TypeScript

Tags: purescript

In TypeScript, there is a technique by which one can `import` an image as a `string`.

`import` the image file in TypeScript source code,

```js
import spinner from 'assets/loading_spinner@2x.png';
```

and then in the `.js` produced by the `tsc` compiler, there will be a line like

```js
var spinner = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA.....";
```

How could we accomplish the same thing in PureScript? The usual [foreign module](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/guides/FFI.md#foreign-modules) technique won't work, because it's the `tsc` compiler which does this “image import.”

### References

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#untyped-imports

https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets

[Webpack & Typescript image import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638454/webpack-typescript-image-import)

Comment: It is Webpack (or a different capable bundler), that converts import module specifiers, not the TypeScript compiler itself. [Wildcard module declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations) let `tsc` just ignore these imports, so no compile error is emitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org) and an appropriately configured `@rollup/plugin-url`

**Assets.purs**

```hs
module Assets where
foreign import spinner :: String
```

**Assets.js**

```js
"use strict";
exports.spinner = require('assets/spinner.png').default;
```