# How to bundle code that defines and uses a require value in webpack

Tags: webpack, purescript

I have some PureScript code that looks like this

```
module Types.ScriptLookups2 where

import Prelude

require :: Unit
require = unit
```

and it gets compiled to the JavaScript code

```js
// Generated by purs version 0.14.9
"use strict";
var Data_Unit = require("../Data.Unit/index.js");
var require = Data_Unit.unit;
module.exports = {
    require: require
};
```

It seems, at least by default, webpack is not smart enough to redefine the earlier `require`s and then leave the final one alone. What happens instead is that webpack doesn't touch the `require` function at all, leading to errors because there is no require in the browser. Is there any webpack configuration I can do to fix this, or do I need to work around it by other means? Unfortunately in the real code, this comes from a dependency, so it's not as easy as renaming it and moving on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342075/import-images-like-in-typescript

Comment: Not sure if upgrading PureScript is an option for you, but PureScript 15 emits ES modules instead. This might circuvent the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. But I got the authors to rename the function, it was an internal one anyway.