# Using image imported in Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm creating a project with Typescrip, Three.js and Webpack.

For this project I need to put an icon inside the view to show it in fullscreen.

To achieve this I followed the above thread:
[Typescript image import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100401/typescript-image-import)

My **import-png.d.ts**

```
 declare module "*.png" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
 }
```

My image import:

```
import * as fullscreenIcon from "./resources/fullscreenIcon.png";
```

My function to add the icon:

```
private addFullscreenIcon(): void {
   const fullscreen = document.createElement("div");
   const icon = document.createElement("img") as HTMLImageElement;

   console.log("fullscreen", fullscreenIcon);

   icon.src = fullscreenIcon.default;
   fullscreen.appendChild(icon);

   this.canvas.append(fullscreen);
}
```

On the page console I got this:

[image: Console error]

My html structure, with the div generate by the `const fullscreen = document.createElement("div");` command, is:

[image]

And my bundled folder structure is like this:

[image: Folder structure]

In the console the image name is `627aac9ac2a7a147efb902c908a25b2c.png` but in the folder structure is `fullscreenIcon.png`

So if `icon.src = fullscreenIcon.default;` is not working, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file-loader` produces a module with a CommonJS export assignment, not a default export.  Either enable the `esModuleInterop` TypeScript compiler option to make export assignments interoperable with default exports, or change your declaration to:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export = value;
}
```

and remove the `.default` from your code.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42479216) for a little background on the different kinds of imports and exports (it doesn't cover TypeScript though).

Comment: That worked for the file reference, on top of that I also had a problem coping the file to the "build" folder. Also solved that and everything started to work.